# Java Equals() method not working as expected

Tags: java

This is my code snipped to check if the two strings are anagrams of each other:

```
    String str="jesus";
    String str2="susej";
    char []c1=str.toCharArray();
    char []c2=str2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c2);
    Arrays.sort(c1);
    System.out.println(c2);  //ejssu
    System.out.println(c1);  //ejssu

    System.out.println(c1.equals(c2)); //false
```

I thought that the `==`operator will return false since they do not share the same memory reference. Isnt the `equals` method supposed to check if the value of the two objects are the same? I thought this would return `true`. Why am I returning false?

Comment: Please search first for [java array equality test](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+array+equality+test). It's all easy to find if you just look.

Comment: I totally forgot Arrays does not override the equals method. I feel so dumb.